# MVC Controller is not access value from View using Json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a code to send a value from `Json` and fetch the result based on value.

JSON Code is:

```
$.getJSON('/Home/SearchResult/' + cityname, function (data) {
    var items = '';
    $.each(data, function (i, city) {
        items = city;
    });
    $('#Result').html(items);
});
```

and at controller code is

```
public JsonResult SearchResult(string cityname)
{
    var result = cityname;
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

but when I am checking value at controller on cityname variable it is showing null value, while I checked values passed on browser then it is passing right value. like 
`Request URL:http://localhost:58301/Home/SearchResult/Meerut`

I am not getting that why value is not showing on controller.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a route that matches the URL you're trying to use. Have you used Fiddler or Glimpse before?

Comment: Try `$.getJSON('/Home/SearchResult', { cityname: "Meerut" }, function(data) {...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke not working same issue.

Comment: Please show the route specified for `SearchResult` action.

Comment: @Ankur, Just tested and it works fine. Are you sure you hitting the controller?

Comment: `SearchResult` action is not getting value sent by `Json` function. and route is fine i have checked this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes i am hitting the controller action but value is not coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work,I have tested it in my local and it worked.

```
$.getJSON('/Home/SearchResult/', { cityname: "KL" }, function (data) {
    var items = '';
    $.each(data, function (i, city) {

        items = city;
    });
    $('#Result').html(items);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$.getJSON('/Home/SearchResult/', cityname, function (data) {
        var items = '';
       $.each(data, function (i, city) {
           items = city;
        });
        $('#Result').html(items);
    });
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    dataType:"json",
    url: '/Home/SearchResult',
    data: {cityname: 'Meerut'},
    success: function(data){ //write code}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
In script page

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/ActionmethodName',
    data:  data: '{"parmeter":"' + parmeter+ '"}',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result){}
});
```

In Controller

```
  Public JsonResult ActionmethodName(String parmeter)
    {
      var Message = parmeter;
      return Json(new { Message = Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet});
    }
```